# Slide between couple of fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-sliding

I want to slide between fragments - not the whole screen , only part of it.

[image]

I saw `SlidingPaneLayout` but it didnt quite do what I wanted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`ViewPager`](http://developer.android.com/training/animation/screen-slide.html) to slide Fragments. Click [here](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/04/android-tutorial-using-the-viewpager.html) for tutorial.

Comment: can i use ViewPager inside another fragment?

Comment: Yes, ViewPager can be used inside fragment.It is perfectly possible to put a ViewPager inside a Fragment, so long as the contents of the ViewPager do not themselves contain fragments. Since the concrete implementations of PagerAdapter supplied by the Android Support package use fragments, you have to roll your own fragment-less PagerAdapter to put the ViewPager in a fragment.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to place you slider in specific position, simply adjust ViewPager:

```
    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/pager"
    android:layout_width="100sp"
    android:layout_height="100sp" />
```